# How to use common trace id?

Tags: c#, logging, trace

I want to use common trace id. I'm using following code.

```
 public void method1(){
      using (new Tracer(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
        {
            //my code
        }
  }
  public void method2(){
      using (new Tracer(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
        {
            //my code
        }
  }
```

Here guid is my trace id. But different trace id generating for every method call. I want keep it as unique. How to achieve this?. (note : I call method1,method2 from some different client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get info about class name and/or your .NET <= 4.0, use [StackFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx). You'll get some overhead with StackFrame. If you don't need to get the name of class and you use .NET >= 4.5, here is [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GmQa6s). It uses [Caller Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653988.aspx). :

```
namespace Tracer
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    sealed class CallerInfoTracer : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly string _message;
        private readonly string _memberName;
        private readonly string _sourceFilePath;
        private readonly int _lineNumber;

        private bool _disposed;

        public CallerInfoTracer(string message, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
            [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
        {
            _message = message;
            _memberName = memberName;
            _sourceFilePath = sourceFilePath;
            _lineNumber = lineNumber;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_disposed) return;

            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", _message);
            Console.WriteLine("MemberName: {0}", _memberName);
            Console.WriteLine("SourceFilePath: {0}", _sourceFilePath);
            Console.WriteLine("LineNumber: {0}", _lineNumber);
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Method1();
            Method2();
        }
        public static void Method1()
        {
            using (var tracer = new CallerInfoTracer("Desc1")) { }
        }
        public static void Method2()
        {
            using (var tracer = new CallerInfoTracer("Desc2")) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use single scope?

Comment: @Karthikeyan, what do you mean?

Comment: Its not good to use using in every method. So is it any ways are there for avoid it?